# sort function problem with strings containing square brackets

Tags: matlab, sorting

As shown below, when string contains a square bracket, sorted array is not in a correct ascending order. Is there a way to work around this problem?

**BAD**

Input:

```
 A = {'[Test2]','[Test]','[Test1]'}
 sort(A)
```

Output:

```
'[Test1]'    '[Test2]'    '[Test]'
```

**GOOD**

Input:

```
A = {'Test2','Test','Test1'}
sort(A)
```

Output:

```
'Test'    'Test1'    'Test2'
```

Comment: The behavior is expected. From the docs: `If A is a cell array of character vectors or a string array, then sort(A) sorts the elements according to the code order for the UTF-16 character encoding scheme.`

Comment: @UnbearableLightness Thanks for the info. My version of MATLAB does not contain this information. R2014a. Any workarounds?

Comment: _sorted array is not in a correct ascending order_ How not? `]` comes after `1` and `2`

Comment: @LuisMendo You are correct. I wasn't thinking right. I meant to say "not intuitively" sorted. Technically, based on the UTF-16 list, sorting is definitely accurate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the comment explained, the result is expected, since `1` or `2` is before `]`:

```
sort(']1')
ans =
'1]'
```

If you want to ignore the brackets in cell elements, you can do

```
A1 = regexprep(A, ']$', ''); % remove ending ']'
[~, ind] = sort(A1);
A_sorted = A(ind);
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can concatenate the cell array then split the string using the delimiters `[` and `]` to form a cell array of strings that don't contain bracket and sort the cell then use the indexes of the sorted element to reorder the original cell array.

```
str = [A{:}];
[~,idx] = sort(strsplit(str(2:end-1), {'[',']'}));
result = A(idx)
```

Comment: +one. A regex is a bit overkill here. To add to your answer, if OP were using a more recent MATLAB versions he could use `[~,idx] = sort(extractBetween(A,'[',']'));`

Comment: Interesting! If you post your comment as an answer I will upvote it :)

Comment: This solution only works for the example provided though. If the string is a bit different, it doesn't work. For example `A = {'abc[Test2]','abc[Test]','abc[Test1]'}`. What I am looking for is a way to ignore square brackets in sorting for all type of strings.